# Is there any way to build probability distribution of a tuple?

Tags: probability

I'm looking for a way to build a probability distribution of tuples.

For example, I want to build a probability distribution of working hours, (start time, finish time), not just a single value like start time or finish time.

Is there any theory or technique to do it?

Comment: You may build a probability distribution on any set with a sigma-algabra. This includes all finite sets (and of course finite cartesian products or powers of finite sets), all sets on which you can build a topology (you can take the Borel sigma algebra), etc. So yes, you can build a probability distribution on tuples, with some reasonable conditions.

Comment: For instance, if you take times in minutes, then indexing the minutes with $E_n=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $n=1440$, you may define $p(\omega_{ij})=\frac{1}{n^2}$ with $i$ and $j$ running on $E_n$ (and $\omega_{ij}$ is the elementary event "start time=i, end time=j"). It's a (uniform) probability distribution on couples of timestamps.

Comment: You could just build a joint distribution.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I barely understand about a sigma-algebra or Borel. But I understand your example. If I have samples of start time and end time, then I can count frequency of (w_ij)s. And then I can use their relative frequencies as their probability, or I can take kernel density estimation. Is it right?

Comment: @Henry Do you know how to make joint distribution from samples in the situation that I don't know their independency or correlation?

Comment: @JHLee Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Another question. I'm trying to make histogram. But (w_ij)s are not numeric. What can I do for this? If I have to make 3-D pdf where x-axis is i, y-axis is j, and z-axis is pdf value, is this the same as joint distribution function of i and j?